# Unable to select the option values under the select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

Java Script :

```
var numArray = {"01":"Monday","03":"Wednesday","05":"Friday"};

$.each(numArray , function(key,value){
                    $("#weekDay").append($("<option></option>")
                             .attr("value",key)
                             .text(value)); 
});
```

JSP :

```
<tr >
<td>
<select id="recurringType" name="recurringType" style="width: 100px; size: 50px" ></select> 
</td>
</tr>
```

The values are populating but I am unable to select . Its selecting only the monday not the other values . Am I doing anything wrong

Comment: how are you selecting the other values... `monday` will be selected by default because that is the first entry

Comment: What do you mean by "select"? As in, clicking them with the mouse, or selecting automatically from JS? If you want them all selected at the same time you'll need to add the `multiple` attribute to the select element.

Comment: `$("#weekDay").val('05')` will select `Friday` - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v27uxq18/

Comment: I am trying to select the values by mouse click and its not selecting the values even i select the value " Friday" from the drop down its selecting the first one which was "Monday"

Comment: @Arun P Johny and all There is action happening on the drop down when a radio button was selected and its my bad that both share the same id and every time I select one of the item it loading instead of selecting the value and the problem solved .

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `option`s to a select with another id.
Change you code as below.

```
$.each(numArray , function(key,value){
      // $("#weekDay").append($("<option></option>") - wrong
      $("#recurringType").append($("<option></option>")
                         .attr("value",key)
                         .text(value)); 
});
```

Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/mrLe45he/